# proper underscores in class attributes

Tags: c++, autocomplete

Well, today, I had an intense discussion with one of my colleagues about `underscores` in attributes' names. While some libraries I work with put it in the start of the name, others put it last.

Is the recommended standard to put it first, and if so, why do others like `PCL` library put it last?

Also, Is there a special shortcut in msvc to suggest only underscored variables?

Comment: You could make aliases using `#define`s.

Comment: Leading underscores are reserved in the global namespace. So to avoid confusion and bad habits, avoid them also for class member names. Code with leading underscores in names, other than C++ implementation code, generally communicates "this was coded up by a novice, or an incompetent" (but I've used it sometimes for function arguments, there's no good convention for that so choosing lesser evil).

Comment: A more general question has been discussed in great detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: Are you asking "Do I put underscores at the start or end of attributes' names?" If so, then why are you convinced you need to do either of those?